# "$10^{\mathrm{th}}$" Index skipped in M-theory

Tags: string-theory, conventions, notation

Why is it that in M-theory, the 11-dimensional vectors are labelled with indices $0 \dots 9,11$. For example, the spatial momentum components are $p_{1}, \dots, p_{9}, p_{11}$. Why is the $10^{th}$ index skipped?

Comment: I think it's because it's common to talk about compactifying on the M-theory circle (the 11th direction), and referring to $x^{11}$ and the KK momentum on the circle $p_{11}$ is less confusing that if they were $10$'s

Comment: That’s it? There’s no physics behind it?

Comment: I mean it's just notation, some textbooks/papers use this, some don't. I guess one's notation should minimize potential confusion, and possibly this helps

Comment: it's like the 4th index that's skipped in the gamma matrices